# DateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") inside linq threw an error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

DateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") inside linq is throwing an error. Here is my code:

```
public IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel> GetAllEmployees()
{
    List<EmployeeViewModel> vm = (
        from a in db.Employees
        select new EmployeeViewModel
        {
            EmployeeId = a.EmployeeId,
            EmployeeName = a.EmployeeName,
            HiredDateString = a.HiredDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
            HiredTimeString = a.HiredDateTime.ToString("h:mm tt"),
            Description= a.Description
            }).ToList();
    return vm;
}
```

EDIT: HiredDateString and HiredTimeString are strings inside the ViewModel.

For which I got following error:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.NotSupportedException</ExceptionType>
```

If I simply use: *a.HiredDateTime.ToString()* it won't throw an error. But it gives me full DateTime string; I want to get date and time strings separately.
Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Is `a.HiredDateTime` a `DateTime` or a `string`? Looks like it could be a `string`

Comment: Why do you want to store dates as strings? that's always bad idea. If you want to display them a certain way, do it in the view layer

Comment: @BobKaufman It's a string

Answer (score 4):

You can't datetime format in linq expression.You should take this:

```
HiredDateString = a.HiredDateTime,
```

and you should format this data when show.

For example in razor page:

```
foreach (var item in vm )
            {
                @item.HiredDateString.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
            }
```

Comment: I found the solution: I just missed .ToList() or .AsEnumerable()
As I did db.Employees.AsEnumerable() , it worked as expected.

Comment: Some rando just marked my question duplicate. But by no means its a duplicate one. Also down-voted it. These so called 'experts' never let new-comer to do something good. Clearly, deep down, they want to stifle new comers.